# How to prevent maruku from creating IDs on its own

Tags: haml, markdown, maruku

I'm using Maruku as a markdown filter in HAML, and it creates huge useless (for me) IDs on every single header.

So if I have something like this

```
## This is a header
```

It'll make

```
<h2 id="this_is_a_header">This is a header</h2>
```

Which at a certain point starts to become ridiculous, and populates my HTML with a bunch of IDs I do not need, nor want, since Maruku provides me with a way to provide my own IDs,

```
## {#id} This is a header
```

Is there any way to prevent it's behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maruku is obsolete](http://benhollis.net/blog/2013/10/20/maruku-is-obsolete/) and instead you should consider switching over to kramdown (now MIT-licensed).

kramdown allows you to [switch off auto-generation of header IDs like so](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/documentation.html#usage):

```
puts Kramdown::Document.new("# Header with spaces #", :auto_ids => false).to_html
```

Also in kramdown, if you want to [set your own ID attribute](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/quickref.html#block-attributes) on the header, you can do the following:

```
raw_text = "# Header with spaces #
  {: #pumice-stone}"

puts Kramdown::Document.new(raw_text, :auto_ids => false).to_html
```

Output:

```
<h1 id="pumice-stone">Header with spaces</h1>
```

Keep in mind the custom attribute (`{: #pumice-stone}`) follows on the line directly under the block level element you wish to apply it to.